# Is Azure Synapse Analyitcs supporting R Language?

Tags: azure-synapse

Apart from the image below I can't find documentation on this topic. I also tried creating a new notebook from my Synapse Workspace but I can only choose between PySpark, Scala, .NET Spark and Spark SQL.

[image]

Also, is there any chance to make work with Synapse and R together? Maybe an Azure Databricks instance using Synapse just as Datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R is not support at this time . Can you share the document which has the above image , we will work to update that .

Comment: Thanks for your response.
About the shared image, i took it from an hold website post.